# Accessing image data from google cloud buckets as a ML dataset

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory, gcsfuse

Please help if you can! I have a lot of individual images stored in a google bucket. I want to retrieve individual images from the bucket through google colab. I have already set up a connection via gcsfuse but I can still not access the images.

I have tried:

```
I = io.imread('/content/coco/Val/Val/val2017/000000000139.jpg')
I = file_io.FileIO('/content/coco/Val/Val/val2017/000000000139.jpg', 'r')
I = tf.io.read_file('/content/coco/Val/Val/val2017/000000000139.jpg', 'r')
```

None have worked and I am confused.

io.imread returns "None"

file_io.FileIO returns "tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io.FileIO at 0x7fb7e075e588"
which I don't know what to do with.

tf.io.read_file returns an empty tensor.

(I am actually using PyTorch, not Tensorflow but after some google searches, it seemed TensorFlow might have the answer.)

Comment: _file_io.FileIO returns "tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io.FileIO at 0x7fb7e075e588" which I don't know what to do with._ Have you checked the documentation for that method?

Comment: Yeah, I went looking for about two hours but didn't get anywhere. The documentation is a bit of a mess. I'll be trying again today.

Comment: Yeah, I went looking further and have now accessed that filetype and have determined that this too returns an empty file. I am still very confused. I uploaded all of those files and can access them on the bucket console page, but when I access via python they are suddenly empty. The Google documentation is no help, and multiple related StackOverflow Pages dance around the issue. (There seems to be a solution for python 2 but not Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

Is unclear to me if your issue is with copying files from Google Cloud Storage to Colab or accesing a file in Colab with Python

As stated in the [Colab documentation](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=S7c8WYyQdh5i) In order to use Google Cloud Storage you should be using the gsutil tool.

Anyways I tried myself to use the gcsFUSE tool by following this steps and I was able to see the objects of my bucket by running the !ls command

Steps:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

Once you run this, a link will be generated, you can click on it and get the signing in done.

```
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-bionic main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
!apt -qq update
!apt -qq install gcsfuse
```

Use this to install gcsfuse on colab.

```
!mkdir folderOnColab
!gcsfuse folderOnBucket folderOnColab
```

Replace the folderOnColab with the desired name of your folder and the folderOnBucket with the name of your bucket removing the gs:// preceding the name.

By following all these steps and running the `!ls` command I was able to see the files form my bucket in the new folder in Colab.